# Как должна быть устроена аутентификация в SPA приложении?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, auth, spa

Я использую связку  Laravel (для `API`) + Vue (для SPA). Для аутентификации в `API` используется Laravel Passport. Возник вопрос, как правильно организовать аутентификацию в моём SPA приложении.

При логине, например, пользователю выдается Personal Access Token. Что делать дальше? Конкретно не понятны два момента:

- Где хранить токен доступа к своему `API`, в `localStorage`, `cookie` или еще где-то?
- Как производить аутентификацию в само SPA, для того чтобы ограничить доступ к некоторым роутам. Просто хранить флажок `isAuthenticated` в `localStorage`? Как вообще принято это делать?

Comment: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components` - вы уже выполнили эту команду?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, нет, но как это может мне помочь? Команда создаст компоненты для работы с токенами и клиентами, и всё.

Comment: Есть проект, который так и называется [laravel-vue-spa](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa) - в нем на большинство ваших вопросов есть ответы.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, да, я его скачал сразу, изучил. Просто сомневался, всё ли там правильно реализовано :) Но спасибо за вашу рекомендацию.

Comment: Еще [vue-auth](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth) есть, но его не просматривал. Сам в `localStorage` храню. В `axios` `bearer token` добавляю при каждом запросе.

Answer (score 1):

> Где хранить токен доступа к своему API, в localStorage, cookie или еще
> где-то?

Я храню в токены в localStorage.

> Как производить аутентификацию в само SPA, для того чтобы ограничить доступ к некоторым роутам. Просто хранить флажок isAuthenticated в localStorage? Как вообще принято это делать?

При загрузке страницы можно отправлять на API запрос аля site.com\api\whoami, который будет требовать авторизации и возвращать авторизованного пользователя и, как самый простой вариант, при успехе записывать в localStorage isAuthenticated true, в противном случае - isAuthenticated false.